# Unable to Authorize Salesforce org using SFDX : Trailhead

Tags: salesforcedx, trailhead, salesforcedx-cli, lightning-web-components

Installed VS code , Salesforce CLI.

iam doing salesforce trailhead Lightning web components. when i Authorize an org, keep on getting

> ERROR:  getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND login.salesforce.com
>   login.salesforce.com:443. 18:51:45.434 sfdx force:auth:web:login
>   --setalias vscodeOrg --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername ended with exit code 1

and

browser redirect to http://localhost:1717/OauthRedirect?code=XXXXX&state=df30635cbef2

I have added proxy settings in VS code also

```
set HTTP_PROXY=https://myID:pwd@proxy:port
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://myID:pwd@proxy:port
```

someone encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 8):

Following my steps to make this work

1. Login into the TrailHead Org.
2. Log out, and copy the URL you have after you logout
3. Use this URL to sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias vscodeOrg --instanceurl   --setdefaultusername

Example:
sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias vscodeOrg --instanceurl https://playful-goat-jcbl-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/  --setdefaultusername

Wrong URL:
https://playful-goat-jcbl-dev-ed.lightning.force.com

Comment: hi, its proxy issue. its working out of office network. so i completed the trailmix using my mobile data.. also the same its working in my Intellij immuninated cloud plugin.but still iam not convinced this VS code proxy issue.digging more on this.

Comment: This solved my problem. In my case, I was not using the correct domain of my Trailhead playgroud (and not XXXX.lightning.force.com). But instead of https, I had used http. Logging out of trailhead gave me the correct URL.

Comment: @henriqueCabral Best Answer for me, Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @Henrique Cabral. Yor post is very useful to me!

Answer (score 1):

I had some frustration with trying to authorize my trailhead playground org from VSCode, constantly receiving *ERROR running force:auth:web:login: grant type not supported* errors in VSCode and a *localhost refused to connect* error in the browser.

Finally, I just ran the following sfdx command from the command line (not in VSCode):

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -a https://silly-something-phn5av-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
```

Returned the following:

```
Successfully authorized anonymous@silly-something-phn5av.com with org ID 00D4W123452UxdJUAS
You may now close the browser
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and want to share my solution. First of all, I read a ton of information about this problem from google and tried different solutions, but nothing could help me. I use Ubuntu 20.04. So I decided to reinstall Salesforce CLI.
After installing I tried:
sfdx --version,
and see:
sfdx-cli/7.82.0-3d0c527ac6 linux-x64 node-v12.18.3.
The Node version is 12.18.3, BUT I used the latest LTS: 14.15.4.
So I used nvm to install Node 12.18.3 and use this version as the default version. And all works. Hope this information will be useful for those, who search solution.

Comment: Thx. Your solution is working for me!
updated sfdx-cli and Works!!

Answer (score 0):

I deactivated the Windows Defender. Make sure that the port specification in the archive sfdx-project.json in your project doesn't have a port property or is different to 1717. Also, verify that the port 1717 is free using the command:

netstat -ano | findstr 1717

If this port is in use so kill it

TASKKILL /F /PID 17956

Also, i try to connect with my org in my work network and dosent work and with my network (cellphone) works fine.

Comment: Tried all possibilities, its not working in corporate network

Comment: Yes because you need to configure the environment variable of the proxy, wait me and send you the specific info

Comment: In this link you can find how to configurate the proxy, you need to know the url and port of your company but if you company block some url like salesforce (in my case this happened) you should to change your network to a cellphone network or home network 

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli_firewall.htm

Comment: Also, you can talk with you IT department and say that you need access to this domains
https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli
https://registry.npmjs.org

Answer (score 0):

Check and get your proxy settings. Set your proxy in the windows Environment local variable for "HTTP_PROXY" and "HTTPS_PROXY". You may need to log off your machine.

Answer (score 0):

If your are connecting to a sandbox, edit your **sfdx-project.json** file to set *sfdcLoginUrl* to https://test.salesforce.com before you authorize the org.
Here's the config that I'm using

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://test.salesforce.com/",
  "sourceApiVersion": "50.0"
}
```

> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_any_org.htm

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of the mentioned worked for me.

Ended up just resetting the org password and creating a new VS Code SFDX project. Only then the Auth Org worked. I also matched the Node version to SF CLI, but unsure if that contributed to the success.

Answer (score 0):

Insane this issue is still around as of 2023. Hopefully I'm the problem and I've somehow managed to miss the permanent/final fix for this issue (???) but I'm still running into this issue as of 1/31/23. I used to be able to switch the port from 1717 to 1771 in the browser address bar when it failed and that would work but this morning even that trick fails for me.

Thanks to this below forum post from [SFDC](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IDtcQAG) I can get in via device auth for now ... but sure hope the built-in/SFDX method gets fixed for good one day.

```
None of the solutions above work, nor should they be used.

Salesforce CLI is just broken,
So until Salesforce fix it use:
sfdx auth:device:login -a MyAlias -r https://<mydomain>--<sandbox>.my.salesforce.com -s
```